# Download JPG from website with no extension

Tags: python

Is there any way I can download an image from a website that has no extension associated with it?  I'm currently using Python to do this but when I try to use the command:

```
url = 'http://dcdbs.ssec.wisc.edu/inventory/image.php?sat=GOES-13&date=2012-06-12&time=03:32&type=Imager&band=2'
urllib.urlretrieve(url)
```

the image is downloaded, however the file is empty.  This command works with images that have extensions.

I'm not all that familiar with urllib.  I'd like to do this preferably with Python, but Java would be ok too.  This seems like a fairly simple thing to do, but I've spent quite a bit of time on it with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by parsing an image?

Comment: "the image is downloaded, however the file is empty." So how do you know the image is downloaded?

Answer (score 5):

You're using the wrong `urllib` function.

```
url = 'http://dcdbs.ssec.wisc.edu/inventory/image.php?sat=GOES-13&date=2012-06-12&time=03:32&type=Imager&band=2'
resp = urllib.urlopen(url)
image_data = resp.read()
# Open output file in binary mode, write, and close.
f = open('aaa.jpg','wb')
f.write(image_data)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks to be working fine for me using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) and [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/):

```
>>> import Image
>>> import requests
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> r = requests.get('http://dcdbs.ssec.wisc.edu/inventory/image.php?sat=GOES-13&date=2012-06-12&time=03:32&type=Imager&band=2')
>>> im = Image.open(StringIO(r.content))
>>> im
<JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=531x220 at 0x1BF7098>
```